# Help me correct my php include path on windows 7, i've hit a block

Tags: php, zend-framework, windows-7, include-path, zfdoctrine

i've been suggested to use the [ZFDotrine](http://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine) from a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743878/do-i-need-to-hack-zendframework1-10-8-doctrine1-2-2-to-get-model-generated) but right now it turns out to be kind of headache where i don't know why zf can't see the zfdoctrine provider.

I have a kind of shady environment on my `windows 7`.i have `xampp 1.7.3` and `zend server5.0.2` on my machine each with a different version of zf.so i downloaded zf 1.10.8 under drive c (`C:\ZendFramework`) and referenced its bin in the `environment variable path`, and its library in `php.ini`. i've removed `c:/xampp/php/PEAR/zend` folder and `c:/xampp/php/zf.bar | zf.php`. i also have netbeans 6.9 created the zf.ini for me.After some issue with NetBeansCommandsProvider i got everything working fine, from command line tool project create to tool from netbeans.

xamp/php.ini

> include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZendFramework\library;"

zendserver/php.ini

> include_path=".;C:\ZendFramework\library"

in zf.ini i have change php.includepath to php.include_path

> php.include_path = "C:\ZendFramework\library;.;C:\Users\sensei\ .netbeans\6.9\zend;C:\ZFDoctrine;"
>   basicloader.classes.0 = "NetBeansCommandsProvider"

So with ZFDoctrine physically under C and referenced in zf.ini i thougth everything would work out but i'm having errors

> Failed opening 'ZFDoctrine\Tool\DoctrineProvider.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZendFramework\library;C:\ZFDoctrine;') in C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 147

for the command `zf enable config.provider ZFDoctrine_Tool_DoctrineProvider`

Apparently when i copy ZFDoctrine folder to C:\ZendFramework\library\zend\ it works.that makes me realize there is something wrong with the include_path.

i'm thinking also about copying it to the PEAR folder but that too, i don't know if that's the best way to go.I just don't understand why it can't find the ZFDoctrine folder.
I'm kinda stuck.Please has anyone successfully using this to share his experience with me?Can you point out what i'm not doing right? thanks for reading this.this is a kind of blocker to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend_Tool uses the include path in zf.ini, so it's this one you need to double check:

> php.include_path = "C:\ZendFramework\library;.;C:\Users\sensei\ .netbeans\6.9\zend;C:\ZFDoctrine;"

What is the correct full path to DoctrineProvider.php? At the moment it's looking for:

> C:\ZFDoctrine\ZFDoctrine\Tool\DoctrineProvider.php

which doesn't look right. Assuming you've extracted the full ZFDoctrine to C:\ZFDoctrine, then should it be:

> php.include_path = "C:\ZendFramework\library;.;C:\Users\sensei\ .netbeans\6.9\zend;C:\ZFDoctrine\library;"

Comment: really dude you made my day! thanks soooooooo much!!.what i've done now does make sens.i've let's say copy the library folder to drive C and rename the it ZFDoctrine.silly me! thanks again Tim